# Maven: retrieve an other jar when building package

Tags: maven

I have two modules where I need to retrieve the .jar from the target folder from module one when I built the second module.

I can only find a solution where I have to put an output directory for the first module to the second, but I want to retrieve the .jar when I built the second one. So the second one has to grab it from the target folder from module one.

Anyone who could help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just include the dependend jar as a dependency for module 2 like you do with all the other jars. Maven will build the modules in the right order automatically.

Comment: Yea, that's what I did, but now I saw that he puts it in the lib folder with the other jars. I was searching in the wrong folder.. stupid from me.

Is there a way that I could say that he has to 'unjar' the content on the same level as module 2?

E.g.:
- class_modul2
- class_modul1

instead of:
- class_modul2
- [libFolder - class_modul1]

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html